# How to invert a matrix by computer with out so much errors

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I was trying to find the inverse of a positive definite matrix with high dimension by computer. However, I tried even for a $5 \times 5$ matrix I cannot invert it correctly. I multiplied the original matrix and the inverse of it returned by the computer, the result is quite close to the identity matrix but not exactly the identity matrix.

Is there better ways (better algorithm etc.) to find the inverse by computer?

Comment: Well. Does the inverse nearly not exist? How close is the determinant to zero? What algorithm are you using now? Using Crammer's rule directly has very bad numerical stability.

Comment: @Rzu At this moment it is not quite close to zero but it actually depends on the data I got from experiments.

Comment: @Rzu I am using the command  to get the inverse directly in Matlab and R.

Comment: Calculate $C=\operatorname{Cond}(M)$, known as condition number. If it is large then your matrix inversion is very sensitive to arithmetic approximations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a package can give you an approximate inverse to $A,$ call the approximation $X,$ an improvement can be found by 
$$ g(X) = 2X - XAX  $$

You are concerned about $AX-I;$ it has small entries but is not quite zero. 
$$ A g(X) - I = A(2X - XAX) - I = -AXAX + 2AX - I = -(AX-I)^2  $$

That is, using some submultiplicative norm for matrices, as soon as $|AX-I|$ is significantly smaller than $1,$ the improvement is considerable.

ADDED: a piece of luck. In the strange world of numerical matrices, you are also worried about $XA-I.$ However,
$$  g(X) A - I = (2X - XAX)A - I = -XAXA + 2XA - I = -(XA-I)^2  $$

Comment: Thanks! Neat and smart solutions! So If I am still not satisfied with the result I got I could use this method again and again until the error is below some threshold, right?

Comment: @Nan yes. This is about as simple as an iterative improvement can get; it is just one of the possible interpretations of Newton's method.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is ill-conditioned you can use regularization. There is the truncated-SVD.

$$ A_{k} = U_{m \times k} \Sigma_{k \times k} V_{k \times n}^{T}  \tag{1} $$

then the pseudo inverse is given as

$$ A^{\dagger} = V\Sigma^{\dagger} U^{T} \tag{2}$$

The pseudoinverse is already a command in matlab.  It is pinv(A)